# Wash away [watermark]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I've came across this tag, [watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watermark). It describes the process of adding symbols on an image to describe its owners.

My view is limited, but I believe that this does not add much to the question. Is there someone expert in watermarking in several different languages and softwares?

Unlike the array tag, for instance, I believe there is no intrinsic knowledge in watermarking that transcends language.

Therefore it seems to fall under:

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

What do you think? :)

Comment: `Is there someone expert in watermarking in several different languages and softwares?` Sure, why wouldn't there be?

Comment: @Servy again, my view is limited, but it seems there is nothing in common with this process in different languages. Each one has a different set of image processing utilities that might present problems, but watermarking in itself doesn't seem like a very difficult task.

Comment: The fact that you consider something to be easy doesn't mean there can't be expertise in that subject (If "I think that's easy" was a reason to burn a tag there wouldn't be many left.).  Sure, there will be *some* language specific problems related to the topic (not that that's even a problem, it's perfectly fine to have language-specific problems related to topics that span languages), but that doesn't mean it's not a sensible topic, or that there won't ever be language agnostic issues in the topic.  And it's not like you aren't allowed to have tags for topics that transcend languages.

Answer (score 15):

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Yes.  **Lots.**  Instead of thinking that you're trying to do something unorthodox or off the beaten path with image fingerprinting, I can immediately identify the industry- and practice-standard vernacular of "watermarking" an image.

Then again, watermarking doesn't just apply to images; it could apply to [PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929954/watermarking-with-pdfbox), too.  Depending on the technology stack and approach you want to take, watermarking can be multifarious; at least the [watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watermark) tag describes something purposeful to *start* with.

Not just that, but there are a lot of decent questions which would be harder to find if we removed this tag.

This isn't a tag that's suitable for burnination at all.

Comment: Yeah, like just asking a freaking GIMP/libcaca/png/jpg/pdf-libraries tagged question. There's no need for a tag for each task under the sky!

Comment: @Braiam:  Suppose the library didn't exist, or the library that you wanted to use after evaluating it, was not suitable for the task you had to accomplish.  What then?

Comment: For somethig those language/file format tags have to be useful, no?